# Multiplying all combinations of array elements in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Note: I am not interested in answers of the form 'just do it using for loops' or so, I want to do it the numpyish way.

Im a beginner in Python and I want to do the following using numpy ndarray's:
Given a sequence of numbers `t` and another sequence of numbers `b`, for every `t[i]` I want to compute the list `t[i]*b` and store that as a new row in a final array. Example:

```
t = [3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

then the outcome should be some form of list encoding

```
[
  [3,6,9,12], # 3 * the array of b's
  [4,8,12,16]   # 4 * the array of b's
]
```

In a program I saw recently, this worked out perfectly but when I want to do it by myself, it raises an error:
Running

```
import numpy

t = numpy.linspace(3,4,2)[:, None]
t = t.T

# filled with some garbage numbers
b = numpy.ndarray(shape=(4,1), dtype=numpy.float64, order='C')

res = numpy.dot(t,b)
```

in python (version 3.4) gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Daten\LiClipse_workspace\TestProject\MainPackage\PlayGround.py", line 9, in <module>
    res = numpy.dot(t,b)
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (4,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Question:

How to make this work?

Comment: you need a regular multiplication instead of np.dot; that is, t*b

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, the easy (and arguably "correct") way to do what you want to do: use `numpy.outer()`, not `numpy.dot()`.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> t = [3,4]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4]
>>> numpy.outer(t, b)
array([[ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])
```

This function computes the component-wise product of two 1D arrays - in other words, it multiplies each element of one array by each element of the other array - and returns a 2D array with the results.

Given the way Numpy displays its results, you can think of this as writing the first vector across the top of a rectangle and the second one down the left side, and filling in a multiplication table.

```
 |   1   2   3   4
-+----------------
3|   3   6   9  12
4|   4   8  12  16
```

The function implements a common mathematical operation on vectors, called the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), tensor product, or Kronecker product. Note that the outer product is not commutative; in other words, you get a different result depending on which order you give the arguments. Compare the above result to this:

```
>>> numpy.outer(b, t)
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 6,  8],
       [ 9, 12],
       [12, 16]])
```

Again, you can picture this as writing the first argument across the top, second argument down the side, and multiplying:

```
 |   3   4
-+---------
1|   3   4
2|   6   8
3|   9  12
4|  12  16
```

Numpy's `dot()` function, on the other hand, implements the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) when applied to 1D arrays, or [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) when applied to 2D arrays, or a generalized version of matrix multiplication when applied to higher-dimensional arrays, but I'll ignore that case because it's a little tricky to understand.

- For two 1D arrays, `dot()` multiplies the two first elements together, the two second elements together, etc. and adds them all up, resulting in a number.

  ```
  >>> numpy.dot([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
  32
  ```

  because `1*4+2*5+3*6 == 32`. So basically, it iterates over the indices of each array, multiplies corresponding elements, and adds them up. Clearly, the two arrays must have the same length.

  You can visualize this in a similar way to `outer()`, but instead of writing the 1D arrays along the edge, write them perpendicular to the edge. You should also switch the order, for reasons that will become clear later (but it's really an implementation choice): write the first one on the left and the second one on the top. An example will demonstrate:

  ```
           |   4
           |   5
           |   6
  ---------+----
  1   2   3|  32
  ```

  To calculate the 32, I multiplied elements at the corresponding position in the column above that cell and the row next to it. `1*4`, `2*5`, and `3*6`, and then add them all up.
- For two 2D arrays, `dot()` iterates over *one* axis of each array, multiplies corresponding elements, and adds them up. The axis being iterated over is the last one of the first array, and the first one (actually, next-to-last) of the second array. Clearly, these two axes must have the same length.

  It's easy to understand this operation in terms of the diagram, so I'll jump right to that: suppose you want to compute the matrix product of

  ```
  array([[ 1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6],
         [ 7,  8,  9]])
  ```

  and

  ```
  array([[10, 11],
         [12, 13],
         [14, 15]])
  ```

  in that order. Again, just write the first argument on the side of a rectangle, and the second one over the top, and then you can multiply-and-add to fill in each cell as I did with the 1D example.

  ```
            |  10  11
            |  12  13
            |  14  15
  ----------+--------
   1   2   3|  76  82
   4   5   6| 184 199
   7   8   9| 292 316
  ```

  because, for example, `4*10+5*12+6*14 == 184`.

Now, you might notice that you can use the `dot()` function to do the same thing as the `outer()` function - but your arrays have be 2D and have a dimension of length 1. That's why you had to jump through some hoops (like the `[:, None]` indexing) in your original code sample to make it work. And it has to be the *right* dimension too: it has to be the last dimension of the first array, and the next-to-last dimension of the second array. So in your specific example, where you want to compute the outer product of `[3,4]` and `[1,2,3,4]`, in that order, you need to convert the first list into an array of shape `(2,1)`, and the second list into an array of shape `(1,4)`. If you do that, when you pass them to `dot()`, it effectively constructs this diagram and fills in the cells:

```
     |[[ 1,  2,  3,  4]]
-----+------------------
[[3],|   3   6   9  12
 [4]]|   4   8  12  16
```

I added some brackets to help you relate these requirements to Numpy syntax.

What you were trying to do, in the code sample in your question (`numpy.dot(t, b)`), would have corresponded to this diagram:

```
        | [[1],
        |  [2],
        |  [3],
        |  [4]]
--------+------------------
[[3, 4]]|   ?
```

See, when you try to apply the multiply-and-add procedure to this, it doesn't work, because you've got two elements in one array and four in the other array, and you can't pair them up to do the multiplications. That's the root of the error Numpy shows you.

When you reverse the order, `numpy.dot(b, t)`, you get this diagram:

```
     |[[ 3,  4]]
-----+----------
[[1],|   3   4
 [2],|   6   8
 [3],|   9  12
 [4]]|  12  16
```

That does give you a sensible result, but be careful about whether it's really the one you want. This is an array of shape `(4,2)`, whereas if you fix up the other procedure in the most straightforward way, you would get a result of shape `(1,1)`, or really, just a number. In any given situation, only one of these options (at most) will work. And it seems like the `logistic` function in the [screenshot](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=6faebac) you posted in a comment is expecting a single number to come out of that `dot()` function; it's not going to work with a larger matrix. (Well, it might, but it won't do what you think.)

Comment: Hmm... In the source Im looking at they use '1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(np.dot(b, t) + a))' with ndarrays and it works... I seem to misunderstand something about ndarray * *scratch head* *

Comment: This is what my debugger looks like: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=6faebac b is beta, a is alpha and x is t... the function im trying to understand is 'logistic' which uses 'dot()' (see below in the screenshot)

Comment: Ah I got it: It works when I change the order of b and t in numpy.dot()... Thanks!

Comment: In the `logistic()` function you showed, they are doing something _entirely different_ from what you're asking about here. They're calculating a dot product (which is a single number), not an outer product.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the point that confused me but numpy automatically gets that one does mean component wise multiplication. So no, one does receive more than one number although it is a dot product.

Comment: Happy now? :-) I changed the question.

Comment: @FabianWerner (2 comments up) ohhhhh, I think I see why you were confused now. You were using `dot()` for something that it _can_ do, but is not quite intended for, and I forgot that it can do that, so I didn't understand why you were confused. Let me edit my answer again. (1 comment up) Much better.

Comment: @FabianWerner the edit I just put in should help make things more clear.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an alternative way that does the same computation, but produces a different shape.

```
a = np.array(range(2 * 5 * 3)).reshape((2, 5, 3))
b = np.array(range(4 * 6)).reshape((4, 6))

c = np.zeros((2, 5, 3, 4, 6))
for i1 in range(2):
    for i2 in range(5):
        for i3 in range(3):
            for i4 in range(4):
                for i5 in range(6):
                    c[i1, i2, i3, i4, i5] = a[i1, i2, i3] * b[i4, i5]

d = np.multiply.outer(a, b)

assert np.all(c == d)
```

To compare:

```
>>> np.multiply.outer(a, b).shape
(2, 5, 3, 4, 6)

>>> np.outer(a, b).shape
(30, 24)
```

You can also use this if you want to look smart: `np.einsum('ijk,lm->ijklm', a, b)`